# What (if any) is the connection between The Hunger Games and The Maze Runner?

Tags: the-hunger-games, character-similarity, the-maze-runner

Is there any connection between *The Hunger Games* and *The Maze Runner*, and if so, are the Maze Runner series prequels to the Hunger Games books?

- Both are recovering from an/the apocalypse
- I think the Maze Runner events might be "*the dark days*" that President Snow was referring to in the Hunger Games
- Everyone wears black that's a military person in the Maze Runner, like how the rebels wear black in The Hunger Games
- According to the [hunger games map](https://imgix.bustle.com/rehost/2016/9/13/86f21aee-9853-4d6e-bdbd-be94ef3fb8b5.jpg?w=375&h=211&fit=crop&crop=faces&auto=format&q=70&dpr=2) there's not much land in the world left

Is there anything that would exclude the Hunger Games and Maze Runner from being part of the same fictional universe?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/2nmc2s/the_hunger_games_and_the_maze_runner_took_place/  -In short, the two universes are incompatible.

Comment: They are by different authors. Why would anyone think they are connected?

Comment: I'm wearing black. It is pretty common for various uniforms. Also, based on ending of last book, not likely to create the world of Hunger Games.

Answer (score 1):

As @DJClayworth said in the comments, these two stories are by different authors so I higlhy doubt they are connected.

> - Both are recovering from an/the apocalypse

In The Hunger Games, they are recovering from a massive rebellion against the Capitol, so it's basically a "military apocalypse". In the Maze Runner, the apocalypse was caused by catastrophic solar flares followed by the Flare, which is a virus that killed millions. So these are two different apocalypse with no link between them.

> - I think the Maze Runner events might be "the dark days" that President Snow was referring to in the Hunger Games

When President Snow refers to "the dark days", he refers to the war between the districts and the Capitol. There are absolutly no references to a virus or any pandemic at all in The Hunger Games.

> - Everyone wears black that's a military person in the Maze Runner, like how the rebels wear black in The Hunger Games

This detail is pretty absurd to notice as a connection between the two stories in a way that almost every military person or special force in stories (or real life) are often wearing black. It's just basic gear for military forces or rebels.